# SQL 40 Exception Error on Connection.Open() C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I know there are [several questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21736829/sql-connection-open-exception) in regards to this already, but I have not found one that seemed to help.

I have tested the connection string in SQL Server Object Explorer and was able to connect to it successfully so I am not sure there is anything wrong with the string.

Please note that for privacy/security the string has been slightly modified but still follows the format of the real string.

After it hits Connection.Open(); it throws the SQL 40 error.

```
connection = new SqlConnection("Server=prod.domain.com,port#;database=dbname;UID=user;PWD=pw;Trusted_Connection=No;");
connection.Open();
```

Comment: shouldn't it be Initial Catalog instead of 'database'

Comment: @Silvermind LOOOL it likely should.... thanks.... Debugging a DLL from 2003 is a headache to begin with...

Comment: That's a valid connection string.  Many of the parameters have aliases.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlConnection_ConnectionString

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft would you have any ideas as to why it breaks on open?

Comment: Just all the normal reasons.  Wrong hostname, wrong IP, wrong port, Windows Firewall, network firewall, etc.

Comment: Well, the server and port I know for sure work as I am able to manually connect to sql server with the same info in the string.... I guess I can check with firewall issues.